# Issues with a ggplot2 rainplot funtion figure

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I created this function to represent using a raning plot. It is embedded in a R package I’m building:

```
#' Exploratory Data Analysis: Rainingplot
#'
#' This function creates a rainingplot to represent continuous data. It uses a classification variable
#' @param db D.B_Final databse obtained in the incorporation - data step.
#' @param var1 Dependent variable. It must be a continuous variable
#' @param var2 Classification variable
#' @return A rainingplot classified by the `var2` argument.
#' @export
#'
rainplot_fig<-function(db,var1,var2){
  fig<-ggplot2::ggplot(db, ggplot2::aes({{var1}}, {{var2}})) +
    ggdist::stat_halfeye(adjust = .5, width = .7, .width = 0, justification = -.2, point_colour = NA) +
    ggplot2::geom_boxplot(width = .2, outlier.shape = NA) +
    ggplot2::geom_jitter(height =0.05,size=.9,width = 1, alpha = .3) +
    ggplot2::theme_minimal()
  return(fig)
```

And if I pass the proper parameters using a database I get the following figure:
[image]

I have some issues:

1. How can I modify the space between the distribution figure and the boxplot?
2. How can I give colors to each distribution according to the classes (Variante 1, Variante 2, Variante 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix the issue with the overlapping boxplot and densities set the `scale` parameter in `ggdist::stat_halfeye`. By default this is set to .9, but to take account of the `justification` and the boxplot width `scale=.7` should work. See the examples below. To color the boxplots, points and/or densities you have to map on the `color` or `fill` aes:

```r
rainplot_fig <- function(db, var1, var2) {
  ggplot2::ggplot(db, ggplot2::aes({{ var1 }}, {{ var2 }})) +
    ggdist::stat_halfeye(
      ggplot2::aes(fill = {{ var2 }}),
      adjust = .5, width = .7, .width = 0, justification = -.2,
      point_colour = NA, scale = .7
    ) +
    ggplot2::geom_boxplot(ggplot2::aes(color = {{ var2 }}),
      width = .2, outlier.shape = NA
    ) +
    ggplot2::geom_jitter(ggplot2::aes(color = {{ var2 }}),
      height = 0.05, size = .9, width = 1, alpha = .3
    ) +
    ggplot2::theme_minimal()
}


rainplot_fig(iris, Sepal.Length, Species)
```

[image]

```r
library(palmerpenguins)

rainplot_fig(penguins, bill_length_mm, species)
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (`stat_slabinterval()`).
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_boxplot()`).
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (`geom_point()`).
```

[image]